# mktemp fails when used in bash script

Tags: bash

In Mac OS X, I have no trouble with mktemp when used in Terminal directly, but the same command in a bash script fails.  What am I doing wrong?

**DIRECTLY:**

```
Air2:~ jk$ mktemp -t "$0"

/var/folders/dq/g6bjxff136515xqlntckj0hc0000gn/T/-bash.74Kw3y9E
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
#!/bin/sh
mktemp -t "$0"
```

**SCRIPT RUN:**

```
Air2:~ jk$ ~/Desktop/Temp/junk.sh

mktemp: mkstemp failed on /var/folders/dq/g6bjxff136515xqlntckj0hc0000gn/T//Users/jk/Desktop/Temp/junk.sh.VrRRi9qE: No such file or directory
Air2:~ jk$
```

Comment: You don't have a directory named `/var/folders/dq/g6bjxff136515xqlntckj0hc0000gn/T//Users/jk/Desktop/Temp/`.

Comment: What if you run `./junk.sh` from within your `~/Desktop/Temp` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a directory named `/var/folders/dq/g6bjxff136515xqlntckj0hc0000gn/T//Users/jk/Desktop/Temp/`.

Notice that `$0` is `~/Desktop/Temp/junk.sh` when you use it in the bash script and the ~ gets expanded as well. So, rather than creating a simple temporary file in the current directory, mktemp is now trying to create the file in a directory 4 levels deep from the current directory. Since it doesn't exist, your command fails.

From the man page of `mktemp`:

> ```
>    -t     interpret TEMPLATE as a single file name component, relative to a 
>           directory: $TMPDIR, if set; else the  directory specified via -p;
>           else /tmp [deprecated]
> ```

So, there you have it from the horse's mount. The parameter to `-t` should be a single file name component and not a path value.

Comment: Thank you, guys.  All makes sense and works now.  I should have fully read the man page!